# How can I draw a border with squared corners in wpf?

Tags: wpf, graphics, line, border

You know, like Battlestar paper! I have given this a few goes but now I'm stumped. I haven't yet gone down the geometery route, so I'll explain this as best as I can.

I'd like the border to be sizable, but contain fixed-size corners, just like CornerRadius does. Instead of rounded corners, I'd like them to be tapered, like:

```
/---------\
|         |
|         |
\_________/
```

I've done two attempts at this:

1. My first attempt attempts to manipulate a border class. This just doesn't work, as stretching the shape ruins the geometry and scale.
2. The second attempt was a bit more out the box. Literally. I created a 3x3 grid and filled it with 4 borders, each with a thickness of 2,0,0,0 - 0,2,0,0 - 0,0,2,0 and 0,0,0,2 respectively. The final step, is the join the borders up with a Line. Here where my question lies....

### First attempt

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.Resources>
         <Style x:Key="MyPoly" TargetType="Polygon">
            <Setter Property="Points">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <PointCollection>
                     <Point X="0.10" Y="0.01"/>
                     <Point X="0.50" Y="0.01"/>
                     <Point X="0.60" Y="0.10"/>
                     <Point X="0.60" Y="0.50"/>
                     <Point X="0.50" Y="0.60"/>
                     <Point X="0.10" Y="0.60"/>
                     <Point X="0.01" Y="0.50"/>
                     <Point X="0.01" Y="0.10"/>
                  </PointCollection>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
      </Grid.Resources>
      <Border
         Width="100"
         Height="100"
         BorderBrush="Black"
         BorderThickness="3"
         CornerRadius="5"/>
      <Grid Width="400"
            Height="300">
         <Polygon
            Stroke="Purple"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            Style="{StaticResource MyPoly}" Stretch="Fill">
            <Polygon.Fill>
               <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" Opacity="0.4"/>
            </Polygon.Fill>
            <Polygon.LayoutTransform>
               <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
            </Polygon.LayoutTransform>
         </Polygon>
      </Grid>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

### Second attempt

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid Width="200" Height="350" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2,0,0,0" Padding="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Line SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" X1="0" X2="1" Y1="1" Y2="0">
                </Line>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0,2,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0,0,2,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The Line is set to scale to the grid size. Setting the Line properties to `X1="0" X2="1" Y1="1" Y2="0"` and using `Stretch="Fill"` expands the Line to the edges. However, it ends up looking like this:

(Annoyingly, I can't post images, I need to go answer someone elses questions to earn some rep. So instead please go to this link to see the line, or paste the above XAML into Kaxaml.)
http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/1996/border1.png

I drew a magenta border around the Grid element hosting the Line, to make the problem more obvious.

How can I expand the line to *really* fill the gap (for example by inflating the drawable area within the grid), or, **is there a better way?**

Also, transformations distort the line, making it thicker. I tried scaling up but there wasn't a consistency to this. Endcaps on the line look just as bad (Triangle for example).

Finally, this method is still flawed, because I want to be able to set the corner size in the future, so having the edge width for the row/column set to 10 seems like a stumbling point. Binding to a property might solve that, I've never done that in a Style though.

Thanks for reading, Tom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WPF border is inheriting from class Decorator. It is pretty easy to write your own Decorator. Below one draws a border around a child with "tucked in" corners.

```
class FunkyBorder : Decorator
{
    public Brush BorderBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BorderBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BorderBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BorderBrush", 
                                    typeof(Brush), 
                                    typeof(FunkyBorder), 
                                    new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Transparent));

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        // TODO, make pen thickness and corner width (currently 10) into dependency properties.
        // Also, handle case when border don't fit into given space without overlapping.

        if (_pen.Brush != BorderBrush)
        {
            _pen.Brush = BorderBrush;
        }

        drawingContext.DrawLine(_pen, new Point(0, 10), new Point(10, 0));
        drawingContext.DrawLine(_pen, new Point(10, 0), new Point(ActualWidth - 10, 0));
        drawingContext.DrawLine(_pen, new Point(ActualWidth - 10, 0), new Point(ActualWidth, 10));
        drawingContext.DrawLine(_pen, new Point(0, 10), new Point(0, ActualHeight - 10));
        drawingContext.DrawLine(_pen, new Point(ActualWidth, 10), new Point(ActualWidth, ActualHeight - 10));
        drawingContext.DrawLine(_pen, new Point(0, ActualHeight - 10), new Point(10, ActualHeight));
        drawingContext.DrawLine(_pen, new Point(10, ActualHeight), new Point(ActualWidth - 10, ActualHeight));
        drawingContext.DrawLine(_pen, new Point(ActualWidth - 10, ActualHeight), new Point(ActualWidth, ActualHeight - 10));
    }

    private Pen _pen = new Pen(Brushes.Transparent, 2);
}
```

Use like this:

```
   <BorderTest:FunkyBorder BorderBrush="Red">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
    </BorderTest:FunkyBorder>
```

Comment: Hi Wallstreet, thanks for responding. This looks nicely comprehensive. I'll give it a shot when I'm back in programming mode tomorrow morning, and let you know how I get on. I was hoping to go with an "all xaml" route so I could swap out Border styles, but forgetting that for now, this might just do it!

Comment: The advantage with implementing it as a class will be easier to reuse. If you just want some Xaml showing the same kind of border you can just define the 8 lines in Xaml. Put them in a grid with one cell and use ActualHeight and ActualWidth from the grid. That was how I figured out the coordinates for the code behind. The resulting visual tree will be the same.

Comment: Ok I've just had a play, and this is definately the way to go. Doing it in pure xaml is more awkward than useful, as it's tricky doing offsets and things like ActualHeight, without an IValueConverter. I modified your code slightly to include a CornerWidthOffset DP, and Triangle capped pens for the edges to reduce the gap effect as shown in my original image. (In my current example, 0.299 works just fine, filling in the holes. Swapping out a Border can be done like this: http://pavanpodila.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!9C9E888164859398!339.entry?sa=601481398. Seems to work quite well. Thanks again!

Comment: All the source for what I've done so far is in here http://www.codescratch.net/files/cornerborder.zip. I hope someone else can find this useful :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the nasty breaks at the end, you could use a Polygon or PolyLine:

```
    <Polygon
        Stroke="Red"
        StrokeThickness="2"
        Points="
            0,1 1,0
            1,0 20,0
            20,0 21,1
            21,1 21,20
            21,20 20,21
            20,21 1,21
            1,21 0,20
            0,1 1,0
        "
        Stretch="Fill"
        />
```

The width I picked is arbitrary...

Comment: Thanks Merlyn, I've just played around with this but I can't get it to play nice. I'll have another bash at it tomorrow. The line is fully overextending its bounds and the square bit looks odd, thanks for the response though.