# Is there a way to use polygon as container?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, containers, polygon

Is there a way to use Polygon as Container (like grid or panel ) in WPF   ?

Answer (score 0):

You might override the "OnRender" method of a border, to render it in different shapes, and use its child Property.This link might help:
[How can I draw a border with squared corners in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678426/how-can-i-draw-a-border-with-squared-corners-in-wpf)